# Dynamic web site plus decoupled content delivery from CMS

Tags: content-management-system

I have a web site project, a mixture of complex dynamic pages and authored CMS-managed content. I have the tools for the complex dynamic part and would like a CMS that allows me to call it to retrieve content that's been approved, i.e. for web site inclusion.

To be clear, I need the complex dynamic part to be the master and the CMS-managed content to be served up as and when I want it.

I had thought they'd be loads of options around this - it being an obvious (to me) thing to want to do. I'd also thought that CMS's would naturally publish API's (web service based ideally) to enable this...but my research so far doesn't seem to show this. Hopefully I'm just missing a trick. Can anyone help?

I've looked, btw, at openText, Alfresco, Jahia, Enfold, Percussion, Interwoven,  EPIServer, Ektron to name a few.

Ideally, I'd like an open source CMS solution if there is one, definitely can't afford the big $ that some of the vendors are looking for.

Comment: I don't quite get what you're trying to do. Are you trying to include web content from CMS that has been been approved into your web application? Since I can only speak for Alfresco I think that's possible in Alfresco.

Comment: Thanks Matjaz. Yes, a large part of the application is very (very) dynamic and doesn't lend itself to CMS delivery, but the another part is really a collection of pages that have to be managed by content editors. So, what I want is to be able to include approved content from the CMS into my dynamically driven web site. Regards Alfresco, yes, I think it does it but it costs $20K to $50K a year for a supported licence. This is way too rich for my project.

Comment: You can always use Alfresco community version... :)

Answer (score 1):

Am I right in assuming you are wanting to use an API or Service to retrieve content from the CMS that has been through some approval process?
This is definately possible with EPiServer, through either the code API or, if more appropriate, a webservice, although I think the price might be an issue here.

Comment: Yes, that's a reasonable summary of what I'm seeking to do. I think EPIServer does do it but looks like $20K plus 20% S&M per annum, which is a lot for managing maybe 30 pages in the CMS.